# Distribution of error by histagrams

Tags: matlab

I have two data set in my hand, they are 720*1 size column matrices , how can ı calculate the error and draw the error ditribution diagram? One of them are actual data and the other is the predicted one.

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming-related question, did you do a Google search? Any chance you can explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In matlab,

```
true = rand(720, 1); % or wherever else you get your data
pred = rand(720, 1); % or wherever else you get your data
errs = pred - true;  % the error in each predicted value
nbins = 50;          % number of bins for histogram
hist(errs, nbins);   % plot the histogram
```

Comment: I don't consider giving away free answers to 'home-work' type questions a good practise.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it was homework. Just trying to help.